# Change legend number range in Altair plot

Tags: python, plot, scale, legend, altair

I am trying to plot time series data in a kind of "climate stripes plot" using the package Altair.
The problem is that I do not know how to change the range in the legend to standardise all my plots with the same colour range and numbers in the legend. At the moment, each time I plot something the legend adapts to the range of the data.

I think the problem is with the "domain" property, maybe is not in the correct place ?

Thank you for your help :)

This is the code for the plot :

```
chart=alt.Chart(source).mark_rect().encode(
    x=('day:O'),
    y='subasins:N',
    color=alt.Color('90%:Q',legend=alt.Legend(title='CH4'), bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=20),
                    scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blueorange'),domain=[1830,2000]) 
    
).properties(width=100).facet(column=alt.Column('month'))

chart.show()
```

[Plots that I get now with different scales in the legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWPYQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the right approach with `domain`, it just needs to be put inside `alt.Scale`:

```
scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blueorange', domain=[1830, 2000])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just change it and now there is no colour in my plot. It has a uniform colour, but the legend have been updated with the right numbers.

Comment: Odd, is there any chance that you can share a sample of your data (`source.sample(100).to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)`) or reproduce this behavior with one of the sample data sets so that I can try it out? There are also [the docs for how domain is used](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html?highlight=domain#adjusting-axis-limits) but it is the way we have described here.

Comment: And double check that the uniform color is not because the color domain was not accidentally set to a range that puts all your data above or below it, then it would get a unifrom color (I think black or dark grey).

Comment: This answer is appropriate for unbinned quantitative domains; for binned domains it's better to use the bin `extent`.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using a bin transform, one way to ensure the scale is consistent is to specify the bin `extent`:

```python
bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=20, extent=[1830, 2000])
```